# How to write a sql script for a range of Oracle assignment date records by different employee's job titles

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an ad-hoc query for a range of assignment date records by employee's job title. These examples are used for the Oracle application assignment table.

First sample:

```
AsgId  Start_Date  End_Date  Job_ID 
  1     1/1/14      6/30/14    10
  1     7/1/14      11/15/14   10
  1     11/16/14    1/10/15    20
  1     1/11/15     3/10/15    10
  1     3/11/15     3/31/15    10
  1     4/1/15      12/31/18   20
```

I have tried analytical functions, in-line views, and other code without success.

Expected report results of 3 date-range records by job title:

```
asgid   start_date   end_date  job_title
 1       1/1/14      11/15/14     10
 1       11/16/14    1/10/15      20
 1       1/11/15     3/31/15      10
 1       4/1/15      12/31/18     20
```

Second sample:

```
EMP_ID START_DATE END_DATE JOB_TITLE 
1      1/1/14     11/15/14 10 
1      11/16/14   11/10/15 10 
1      11/11/15   12/31/15 20 
1      1/1/16     1/31/16  10 
1      2/1/16     12/31/16 10
```

Expected report results of 3 date-range records by job title

```
EMP_ID START_DATE END_DATE JOB_TITLE 
1      1/1/14     11/10/15 10 
1      11/11/15   12/31/15 20 
1      1/1/16     12/31/16 10
```

Comment: . . Can you explain the logic that transforms the samle data to the desired results?

Comment: sample 5 data records
EMP_ID   START_DATE  END_DATE JOB_TITLE
  1       1/1/14      11/15/14   10
  1       11/16/14    11/10/15   10
  1       11/11/15    12/31/15   20
  1       1/1/16      1/31/16    10
  1       2/1/16      12/31/16   10

Expected Report Results of 3 date-range records by job title
EMP_ID   START_DATE  END_DATE JOB_TITLE
  1       1/1/14      11/10/15   10
  1       11/11/15    12/31/15   20
  1       1/1/16      12/31/16    10

Comment: Do you have a column that defines the order?

Comment: The only column that defines the order is the start date. I cannot use the min and max functions because of between job title records of the employee Id.

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Assuming that there are no gaps or overlaps, you can use `left join` and a cumulative sum to determine the islands.  The rest is aggregation:

```
select asgid, job_id, min(start_date) as start_date,
       max(end_date) as end_date
from (select a.*,
             sum(case when aprev.asgid is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by a.asgid, a.job_id order by a.start_date) as grp
      from assignment a left join
           assignment aprev
           on aprev.asgid = a.asgid and
              aprev.job_id = a.job_id and
              aprev.end_date = a.start_date - 1
     ) a
group by asgid, job_id, grp
order by asgid, min(a.start_date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1659de3f41410f6b76523fa8883fb51) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Wow, this is a possible solution to run the query results. There are no date-tracked  gaps because of active assignment records. I will modify my query and get back to you tomorrow. Thanks...

Comment: Your query is not working for a range of date records of each job title. I solved my query below to show accurate results. select a.asgid, a.job_title, a.start_date as beg_date_range, 
(select min(b.start_date)-1
 from asg b 
 where b.asgid = a.asgid
 and   a.start_date < b.start_date
 and   a.job_title <> b.job_title) as end_date_range
from asg a
Thanks, Steve

Comment: @Steve . . . The query works fine when I run it.  I've included a db<>fiddle in the answer.